# I'm not able to find way to upload extra assets zip file in google play console

Tags: android, react-native, assets, google-play-console

I'm currently attempting to upload an additional assets zip file through the Google Play Console. However, I seem to be encountering difficulty in locating the specific section where I should add this file within the console. Could you kindly guide me to the appropriate location for uploading the extra assets zip file in the Google Play Console?

Could you please provide some guidance on how to efficiently upload assets to the Google Play Console?

[image]

I have thoroughly reviewed the provided screenshot and have successfully implemented the necessary code on the app side.

[image]

I have successfully uploaded the bundle to the Play Store console, and it appears to be in order. In the console, we can see our asset folder named 'asset_pack' listed under Asset packs

Comment: Do not use text screenshots and do not quote AI chat bots as source.